# Can covariance (X,Y) be easily expressed in term of Var(X), Var(Y), E(X), and E(Y)?

Tags: probability-theory

Can $Cov(X,Y)$ be easily expressed in term of $Var(X), Var(Y), E(X), $ and $E(Y)$ ?

Comment: E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) you mean?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, I want to avoid E(XY)

Comment: You won't be able to do it without considering *some* statistic that is a function of both random variables.

Comment: Consider (i) $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. standard normal, (ii) $X$ is standard normal and $Y=X$. Both cases have the same $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $\operatorname{Var}(X)$, $\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ but different $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the calculus formula of the covariance.

$Cov(X,Y)= E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) $

Or, you can also have $Cov(X,Y) =\frac{Var(X)+Var(Y)-Var(X+Y)}{2}$= $\frac{E(X^2)-E^2(X)+E(Y^2)-E^2(Y)-Var(X+Y)}{2}$

Comment: This answer was probably before the edit -- the OP stated afterwards that $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ was out of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Covariance, $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$, cannot be expressed exclusively in terms of $\mathsf E(X), \mathsf E(Y), \mathsf {Var}(X), \mathsf {Var}(Y)$.

Covariance involves the term of $\mathsf E(XY)$ , which cannot be expressed in those other terms (unless the rv are uncorrelated, but in which case covariance is simply zero).

$$\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) = \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)~\mathsf E(Y)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf{Var}(X) = \mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2$$

The best you could do would be to use: $\mathsf {Var}(X+Y) = \mathsf{Var}(X)+\mathsf {Var}(Y)-2\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)$ , to express covariance in terms of $\mathsf E(X), \mathsf E(Y), \mathsf {Var}(X), \mathsf {Var}(Y)$ and $\mathsf {Var}(X+Y)$.